# Subflow is not showing the header and footer

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, visual-workflow

My flow has screen interactions sourcing from custom lightning components. i.e. header.cmp, content.cmp and footer.cmp. which works as expected. But another team invoking my flow as a Subflow then the header and footer component pages are not displaying.

i.e.
Flow1(Doesn't have any screen flow elements) invokes Flow2(have screen flow with lightning component pages). As soon as Flow2 is called only the main content is displaying not the header and footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like if Flow 1 doesn't have any screen elements the headers and footer of Flow 2 don't appear. As a workaround Flow 1 is included in the Lightning component and invoked as flow.startflow() with header.cmp and footer.cmp.